# Error in Tomcat Server while reading JSP file

Tags: java, jsp

I have placed `Commonsfileuploadservlet` folder inside webapps. And inside that folder i have written `upload.jsp`

After switching on the tomcat server, while attempting to run the jsp file, the below error comes in the browser.

What might be the cause?

`The requested resource (/Commonsfileuploadservlet/upload.jsp) is not available.`

Comment: I have restarted the server too.

Comment: where did you put that folder exactly? Give full path

Comment: Anything in server logs? Check for most recent log updates in `Tomcat/logs` folder. Do you write raw Java code in JSP using old fashioned scriptlets? The JSP might simply have failed to compile. As quick test of webapp being properly deployed, place a dummy `test.html` file with something like `<h1>Test</h1>` inside.

Comment: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 5.5\webapps\Commonsfileuploadservlet\upload.jsp

Comment: @BalusC am not using any IDEs. Yes, I am writing raw jsp code. What should be done to make JSP file compiled?

Comment: @BalusC even the test.html is not working... same error for that too

Comment: How about the logs? Raw Java code should not go in JSP, but in Servlet. Not directly a technical problem, but it's a semantic and maintenance problem. See also [how to avoid Java code in JSP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/howto-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files).

Comment: Yeah BalusC. You're absolutely correct. I checked the logs. I could find a error stating invalid xml format, for the xml file which was placed inside that folder. I corrected that and now its working fine. Thanks a lot. If u dont mind, can you post the same as answer so  that I can accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*As requested by OP, I am reposting the comment which solved the problem as an answer:*

---

Anything in server logs? Check for most recent log updates in Tomcat/logs folder. It might contain detail about startup errors.